# Negation of: "a divides b"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following proposition that I am trying to prove by contrapositive:

$(\forall{k,n}\in{}Z)(k|n^{2}\longrightarrow{}k|n)$ where Z is the set of all integers.

*proof: (contrapositive)*
Assume $k\nmid{}n$. Then

(1) $n\neq{}k\times{j}, \ {}\exists{}j\in{}Z$

and squaring both sides

(2) $n^{2}\neq{}k(k\times{}j^2)$

And by the closure property of $Z$, $kj^2\in{}Z$

It follows from (2) that $k\nmid{}n^2$

Therfore, $(\forall{k,n}\in{}Z)(k|n^{2}\longrightarrow{}k|n)$ $\blacksquare$

I am a little unsure about (1). My guess is that that assumption is correct since

(3) $a|b \longleftrightarrow{}b=a*n, \ \exists{}n\in{}Z$, would mean that the negation of either creates $a\nmid{}b \longleftrightarrow{}b\neq{}a*n, \ \exists{}n\in{}Z$

Comment: You cannot square both sides of an inequality.  For example, $-1\not=1$, but $(-1)^2=(1)^2$.

Comment: The negation of $k\mid n$ is that $\forall j\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\not=jk$ (whereas you have the existential in $(1)$).

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you for pointing out all the mistakes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original statement is false.  A counterexample is when $k=4$ and $n=2$.  Then $4\mid 2^2$, but $4\nmid 2$.